# What intrinsic property determines whether a function is analytic

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Given we know the value of all order derivatives at a point $x_0$ for a given f(x).

As per my knowledge all the geometric properties like slope, curvature, convexity are functions of solely the derivatives of any order, like in vector calculus, for Serret-Frenet equations, all the parameters can be determined once we know the values of some of the higher derivatives at point and we can construct the function from $x_0$ up to $\infty$ using initial given values at $x_0$ alone however we know this is true only for analytic functions and a limited domain.

**So what is the hidden intrinsic property of a function other than derivatives that prevents it from being analytic ?**

Example:
Take **y=ln(1+x)**, i know the value of function and all derivatives at x=0, both I and nature will use these values to construct the function for x>0, yet, for my taylor series, it will diverge for x>1, still one curious fact is that as i keep on adding terms, function diverges to +$\infty$ for even terms and -$\infty$ for odd terms so it still keeps oscillating about original value and each successive term seems to correct the offshoot introduced by previous term.

**essentially what prevents its convergence ?**

Comment: It is the sum of its Taylor series – which is always the case on $\mathbf C$, but not necessarily on $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @bernard i am unable to understand, kindly elaborate

Comment: I mean it is not necessary true that an indefinitely differentiable function $f$ is such that $\;f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i$. Functions which satisfy this equality are called *analytic*.